# Eclipse Luna, Google Web Kit - Create GWT RemoteService

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Previously, we were using **eclipse Galileo** for our GWT project. Now, we want to upgrade and using **eclipse Luna**.

**Problem 1:-** In eclipse Galileo we use to get option related to Google Web Kit like shown in the following image, through which we use to create the implementation class i.e server class along with on client side we use to get the related service and serviceasync interfaces.

[image: GWT RemoteServicer]

We are not getting this option in eclipse Luna. If we can get help from where do we create GWT Remoteservice from Luna.If there is no direct such option than how to create such classes?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Luna and I've never seen those options.  We always just create the three files manually.  The tricky part is adding it to the web.xml file but since it sounds like you have existing code you can use those as examples.

Answer (score -1):

You must install the GWT plugin. When you upgrade eclipse to a new major version, plugins have to be reinstalled.

See [this site](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) for GWT plugin details.

Comment: Without Gwt plugin I'll be not able to run any project . So we already have the plugin.

Comment: AFAIK It's the plugin that gives you the option. Maybe reinstall everything. Also, why are you using such an old eclipse version? Luna was replaced by Mars over a year ago, and Neon came out 2 months ago. Try installing the latest eclipse and plugins.

Comment: Sir we tried on neon but it was having some bugs so we got to luna. I have  the plugin and sdk installed already. Used this link https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4

Comment: I second @Bohemian's suggestion in reinstalling the plugin and pointing the GWT SDK, to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @vartika try Mars edition - it's not so old. It could be the plugin doesn't work with such an old version of eclipse as Luna.